# How would I loop through an array with .addField

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to make a discord bot that will countdown until a specific date. Right now I have arguments passed into a folder of .json files where the only the event name and release date/eventdate are stored.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
var sendChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '553846848578912257')
setInterval(() =>{

    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
        });
        for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            var input = require(folder+files[i]); 

            if(((new Date(input.releasedate) - currentdate) / days) > 0)
                {
                    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .addField(input.eventName, Math.ceil((new Date(input.releasedate) - currentdate) / days) + ' days until ')
                    //sendChannel.send(Math.ceil((new Date(input.releasedate) - currentdate) / days) + ' days until ' + input.eventName);
                }

            else 
            {
                console.log("arg not passed, invalid or past: "+input.eventName)
            }
        }
        sendChannel.send(embed);
    });
}, 10000);

console.log("Ready")
console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag} (${bot.user.id}) on ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
bot.user.setActivity(`Counting things down | ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
});
```

Right now it would work with the sendChannel.send command and it would send however many files are in the folder but one at a time. I am trying to get them all in an embedded message. The issue is that the .addField will only store the last element in "input". Is there a way to have my program append the .addField after each pass rather than writing over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addField` stores the last input because you create a new `Discord.RichEmbed()` in every loop which creates a new instance and rewrites the previous one.

You should initialize the embed message before the loop and then add the fields in every loop as the following :

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
var sendChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '553846848578912257')
setInterval(() =>{

    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
        // initialize the embed message here
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();

        files.forEach(file => {
        });
        for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            var input = require(folder+files[i]); 

            if(((new Date(input.releasedate) - currentdate) / days) > 0)
                {
                    embed.addField(input.eventName, Math.ceil((new Date(input.releasedate) - currentdate) / days) + ' days until ');
                }

            else 
            {
                console.log("arg not passed, invalid or past: "+input.eventName)
            }
        }
        sendChannel.send(embed);
    });
}, 10000);

console.log("Ready")
console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag} (${bot.user.id}) on ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
bot.user.setActivity(`Counting things down | ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that the syntax was embed.addField to concatenate the files. Then taking the send command and embed variable out of the loop worked perfectly!